# getting rank of a user among all users in table

Tags: sql, database, rank

i have a table like this

```
userEmail | views

  A          8
  B          3
  C          4
  A          2
  B          5
```

i want to get rank of a particular user say B ..

what i am doing is :

```
SET @rank=0;
select @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank , userEmail,sum(views) as views from mtable where userEmail != 'null' Group By userEmail Order By views DESC
```

this will output something like this :

```
rank  | userEmail | views

  1        A          10
  2        B           8
  3        C           4
```

I can get the rank of all users but what if i want to see rank of only one user ??

if i put `where userEmail = 'B'` in above query

i will get this :

```
rank  | userEmail | views

  1        B           8
```

but it should be like this :

```
 rank  | userEmail | views

  2          B           8
```

Comment: Why don't you put a where clause with userEmail ??

Comment: @yogi - I'm guessing that does not satisfy him and he wants some other magic.

Comment: @JAVAGeek - all the ways to do this involve platform specific commands -- are you using SQL Server 2005+ or Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Gordan pointed out my first answer is not very standard.  Here is a standard way of doing the same thing.

```
SELECT T.userEmail, T.views, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY T.views DESC) AS viewRank
FROM (
  select userEmail,sum(views) as views 
  from mtable 
  where userEmail != 'null' 
  Group By userEmail) AS T
Order By T.views DESC
```

There is a special way to do this in sql server 2005+ and Oracle (using the `OVER` clause) but the general answer (which you have to use with mysql) is to use a where clause.  Like this:

```
SET @rank=0;

SELECT T.rank, T.userEmail, T.views 
FROM (
  select @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank , userEmail,sum(views) as views 
  from mtable 
  where userEmail != 'null' 
  Group By userEmail Order By views DESC ) AS T
WHERE T.userEmail='somename@somewhere.com'
```

Comment: Error Code : 1248
Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: As a note, this is not a general solution.  The use of external variables for this purpose is very specific to a particular database engine.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL it's possible with user of temporary table check below query for same.

```
create table #tmp (randomno int,email varchar(10),viewsum int)
insert into #tmp select  ROW_NUMBER() over (order by sum(vi) desc) as 'rank', email,SUM(vi) 
from test
 group by email




select * from #tmp where email = 'B'
 drop table #tmp
```

Comment: This is not mysql and why create a temp table when you can do the over  in the where statement?  Also I think you want RANK() not ROW_NUMBER

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering this because @Hogan claims that to have a general approach.  There is a general approach that works on all SQL databases, and that is not it.

The general approach requires a self join:

```
select t.useremail, t.views, count(*) as rownumber
from t left join
     t tless
     on t.useremail = tless.useremail and
        t.views >= tless.views
group by t.useremail, t.views
```

If you have duplicates on the views, then the following is the equivalent of a dense ranking:

```
select t.useremail, t.views, count(distinct tless.views) as denserank
from t left join
     t tless
     on t.useremail = tless.useremail and
        t.views >= tless.views
group by t.useremail, t.views
```

And, since the query does not explicitly mention the database, in most databases, you can simply use:

```
select t.usermail, t.views, row_number() over (partition by usermail order by views)
from t
```